# Efficiently replicate matrix rows by group in R

Tags: r, performance, matrix, replication

I am trying to find a way to efficiently replicate rows of a matrix in R based on a group. Let's say I have the following matrix `a`:

```
a <- matrix(
  c(1, 2, 3,
    4, 5, 6,
    7, 8, 9),
  ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE
)
```

I want to create a new matrix where each row in `a` is repeated based on a number specified in a vector (what I'm calling a "group"), e.g.:

```
reps <- c(2, 3, 4)
```

In this case, the resulting matrix would be:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    1    2    3
[3,]    4    5    6
[4,]    4    5    6
[5,]    4    5    6
[6,]    7    8    9
[7,]    7    8    9
[8,]    7    8    9
[9,]    7    8    9
```

This is the only solution I've come up with so far:

```
matrix(
  rep(a, times = rep(reps, times = 3)), 
  ncol = 3, byrow = FALSE
)
```

Notice that in this solution I have to use `rep()` twice - first to replicate the `reps` vector, and then again to actually replicate each row of `a`.

This solution works fine, but I'm looking for a more efficient solution as in my case this is being done inside an optimization loop and is being computed in each iteration of the loop, and it's rather slow if `a` is large.

I'll note that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20117458/replicate-rows-of-a-matrix-in-r) is very similar, but it is about repeating each row the same number of times. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034861/efficiently-replicate-matrices-in-r) is also similarly about efficiency, but it's about replicating entire matrices.

## UPDATE

Since I'm interested in efficiency, here is a simple comparison of the solutions provided thus far...I'll update this as more come in, but in general it looks like the `seq_along` solution by [F. Privé](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6103040/f-priv%c3%a9) is the fastest.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

a <- matrix(seq(9), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
reps <- c(2, 3, 4)

rbenchmark::benchmark(
  "original solution" = {
    result <- matrix(rep(a, times = rep(reps, times = 3)),
      ncol = 3, byrow = FALSE)
  },
  "seq_along" = {
    result <- a[rep(seq_along(reps), reps), ]
  },
  "uncount" = {
    result <- as.data.frame(a) %>%
      uncount(reps)
  },
    replications = 1000,
    columns = c("test", "replications", "elapsed", "relative")
)
```

```
               test replications elapsed relative
1 original solution         1000   0.004    1.333
2         seq_along         1000   0.003    1.000
3           uncount         1000   1.722  574.000
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply use `a[rep(seq_along(reps), reps), ]`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option with `uncount`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
as.data.frame(a) %>%
 uncount(reps)
```

-ouptut

```
V1 V2 V3
1  1  2  3
2  1  2  3
3  4  5  6
4  4  5  6
5  4  5  6
6  7  8  9
7  7  8  9
8  7  8  9
9  7  8  9
```

Comment: learned `uncount` from your answer, cheers!

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding Great solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68603750/is-there-an-r-package-to-calculate-1st-order-transition-matrix-from-a-frequency/68604852#68604852)

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option (not as elegant as the answer by [@F. Privé](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68604960/12158757) or [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68605083/12158757))

```
> t(do.call(cbind, mapply(replicate, reps, asplit(a, 1))))
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    2    3
 [2,]    1    2    3
 [3,]    4    5    6
 [4,]    4    5    6
 [5,]    4    5    6
 [6,]    7    8    9
 [7,]    7    8    9
 [8,]    7    8    9
 [9,]    7    8    9
```